# two updatePanels

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Ive got two update panels on my site. Each one has got repeaters. Is it possible to refresh only one of them without need to rebind repeaters inside the other ? thanks for any help

There is One updatePanel:

```
<UpdatePanel runat="server" id ="upd1" UpdateMode = "condicional'>
<ContentTemplate>
     <repeater>
</Contentemplate>
</updatePanel>

<updatePanel runat="server" id="ipd2" >
<COntentTemplate>
    <LinkButton>
</ContentTemplate>
</UpdatePanel>
```

When I click on link button both updatepanels are updated :(

OK the UpdatePanel wasnt updated but it was because of javascript. I need to run that javascipt in order to apply jquery carousele to the repeater in first div. Is it possible keep functionality of the carousel without invoking js code when second updatePanel is updated ?

Comment: Can you post your asp source code ?
Else you can use trigger per update panel

Answer (score 2):

Set the [`UpdateMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx) for the `UpdatePanel` to `Conditional` and set up appropriate triggers that should cause updates.

Answer (score 2):

Set `UpdateMode="Conditional"` and when you want to update  Call `UpdatePanel1.Update();` to update specific updatepanel

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContents">
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the update Mode of the Inner Update panel to Conditional.  Inner update panels are automatically updated by the outer update panels.